# get_avatar not working

Tags: avatar

I'm working on a plugin for showing users via shortcode by their role (in this site's case - authors).  I'm getting a list of user objects using a WP_User_Query statement, then creating the output for each user like this:

```
foreach ( $users as $user ) { ?>

            <div class="sap_author_box">

                <div class="sap_author_pic"><?php get_avatar( $user->user_email, 150 ); ?></div>
                <div class="sap_author_name"><?php
                    echo '<a href="http://curbcollege.org/happytogethertour/author/' . $user->user_login . '">' . $user->display_name . '</a> <span class="smallertext">( ' . $user->age . ' ) - ' . $user->classification . ' from ' . $user->hometown . '</span><br />';
                    echo '<span class="smallertext">Major: ' . $user->major;
                    echo ( empty( $user->minor ) ? '</span>' :  ', Minor: ' . $user->minor . '</span>' ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="sap_author_bio"><?php echo $user->user_description; ?></div>

            </div>

        <?php } // End of $users foreach
```

All the data from the user's profile comes out just fine, except the avatar.  I've tried using $user->ID instead of email, but that doesn't work either.  I know both the email and ID are called correctly because I can echo them onto the page and see them, so it's not that the data isn't getting to the get_avatar function.  What am I doing wrong with get_avatar?  I know some of the authors have avatars because I can see them on the Users list, but not on the output page.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `echo` it:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, 150 ); ?>
```

Comment: Good grief.  The simple things... :)  I've looked at a bunch of tutorials on using get_avatar and didn't notice the echo statement on any of them.  Thanks Eugene!